# Работа с текстовым файлом

Tags: delphi

Доброе время суток. 
  Подскажите решение и если можно не большой пример.

**Задача следующая**

Есть текстовый файл, такого вида

```
  №       Длина     Координата          Примечание 
   3        591               0          114-2012Т1 Я1 Изд1 Пр2 СВ 
   12       601              616         114-2012Т1 Я1 Изд1 ПрРВ 
   11       601              1242        114-2012Т1 Я1 Изд1 ПрРН 
   9        695              1868        114-2012Т1 Я2 Изд1 ПрРН 
   8        695              2588        114-2012Т1 Я2 Изд1 ПрРВ 
   2        1304             3308        114-2012Т1 Я1 Изд1 Пр2 СЛ 
   1        1304             4637        114-2012Т1 Я1 Изд1 Пр2 СП
```

Мне из него нужно создать этикетку такого типа

```
114-2012    Т 1  Я 1
Изд 1       Пр 2    652-652
SS_72x86    6000    68х78 
 СВ         591        д-3
114-2012    Т 1      Я 1
Изд 1       Пр       652-652
SS_72x86    6000     68х78 
 РВ         601        д-12
114-2012    Т 1      Я 1
 Изд 1      Пр       652-652
SS_72x86    6000     68х78 
 Рн         601       д-11
```

и т.д

Помогите, очень нужно.

Comment: @kadekin77, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: отформатировать вопрос - это раз!

второе напишем когда будет выполнено условие №1

Comment: @kadekin77, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм построения результата не очень ясен. Появляется дополнительная информация (константы или переменные), которых нет в исходном тексте.  В общем случае каждую строку надо прочитать в 7 строчных переменных фиксированной длины. Оттуда вытащить по позициям нужные символы (если они переменные).Это касается ваших Т1 и Пр. А потом  выводите в нужном порядке с добавлением отсутствующей информации.
 А что такое "этикетка" в вашем случае?